# Left outer join using the model of the joined table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to do a left outer join in rails, but I need the model objects to be for the joined table.

What I want is a list of the days, with the metrics for each day. I need to have all days regardless of whether or not there were metrics, but I don't want to make a bunch of round trips to the database.

This works, but causes problems because it thinks I have PeriodDay objects when I really want Metric objects:

```
PeriodDay.select("metrics.*").join('LEFT OUTER JOIN metrics ON period_days.date = metrics.date').where('period_id = ?', current_period)
```

I can use find_by_sql on the Metric object, but the query building is more complicated (and conditional) than this simplified example, so I would rather figure out the "rails way" for this problem.

Comment: By definition a LEFT OUTER JOIN like this can result in metric objects that don't exist, so it does not make sense to have metric objects with NULL ids. You need to get PeriodDay objects as the result.

Comment: @Pan Thomakos yes, there could be null ids, but I don't need to reference the ids (no updating, etc). If I have PeriodDay objects then all of the Metric fields are treated as strings, which is a huge PITA.

Comment: The problem is that because you are doing a left outer join, where the primary table is period_days, you have the chance of having a lot of entirely NULL metrics objects with only period_day information. If you were doing a 'metrics LEFT OUTER JOIN period_days' then this would be a different thing.

Comment: I understand the significance of the LEFT OUTER JOIN. See my current workaround as an answer below. This results in the desired outcome, but there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to loop through the records and create Metric objects from the attributes of the PeriodDay object. It doesn't feel efficient, but it is better than making multiple database calls.

```
metrics = []
recs = PeriodDay.select("metrics.*").join('LEFT OUTER JOIN metrics ON period_days.date = metrics.date').where('period_id = ?', current_period)
for rec in recs
  metrics << Metric.new(rec.attributes)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Period has many PeriodDay has many Metric, and that period_id is an attribute of your PeriodDay model, your workaround should be identical to something like this:

```
Metric.includes(:period_day).where(:period_day => {:period_id => @current_period})
```

This doesn't get you a list of days with their respective Metric objects as you mentioned in the original question, but it gets you a list of all Metric objects for a particular period. (unless I'm missing something...)

If you want a list of PeriodDay objects with their included Metric objects, you can use `includes` instead of `joins`.

```
PeriodDay.includes(:metrics).where(:period_id => @current_period)
```

This will execute two queries (one to get period days and the other to get metrics) but it is a lot more readable.

Comment: The first solution doesn't work because I need blank Metric objects for days in the period where a metric object doesn't exist.

The second solution doesn't work because I need metric objects and that returns PeriodDay objects.